# Excluding certain inputs on serialize

Tags: jquery, serialization

I am trying to exclude an input by name (it is a hidden input holding my nonce)

The following question is almost what I am looking for:

[How do I use jQuery's form.serialize but exclude empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields)

but I have 2 questions about the solution there- which states that to serialize form data except for empty inputs and inputs where the value = "."

```
$("#myForm :input[value][value!='.']").serialize();
```

first of all, i can't get it to work with the jquery variable "this"

```
$('#ofform').live('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var serializedReturn = $(this :input[name!='security']).serialize();        
});
```

And secondly I have a seperate form with the id of ofform-reset and if i use:

```
var serializedReturn = $(#ofform :input[name!='security']).serialize();
```

it picks up the inputs in the other #ofform-reset form, AND/OR inputs that aren't enclosed within a  tag.

found the answer in one of my previous questions.  invalid markup of the style:

```
<form id="ofform">
 <div id="toolbar">
 <button id="save">Save</button>
</form>
<form id="ofform-reset">
 <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
</div>
```

now to figure out how to use 2 different buttons to control the same form

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You don't need the `:`, because input is an element not a pseudo selector. Secondly you cannot use an object and a text string like that in your selector. You instead need to supply this as the scope argument to `$()`:

```
$('#ofform').live('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var serializedReturn = $('input[name!=security]', this).serialize();        
});
```

Comment: thanks.  this does work.  except, that the serialization is still picking up inputs from other forms.  it is as if it is serializing everything on the page

Comment: IS one form nested inside the other? because you can do that. Post your markup.

Comment: @prodigitalson You can't have a form inside another one (it is illogical anyway). Or perhaps you had a typo in your comment...

Comment: @Christian: yeah typo... thats EXACTLY what i was getting at :-)

Comment: @Trip: it was jsut an example... one can add additional elements like `select` and `textarea` or exclude things like `input[type=submit]`... depend on whats going on in the form.

Comment: @Ezra sure just add selectors as needed. Though at some point you might want to start using classes or data attributes to define fields to be excluded or included... whichever way you want to go about it.

Comment: Your sample worked for me, I just had to use "form" instead "this": $('input[name!=security]', $('form') ).serialize()

Answer (score 18):

First, you need to invoke the `.find()` method like:

```
var serializedReturn = $(this).find('input[name!=security]').serialize();
```

Otherwise the complete string would go into the css query engine (Sizzle).

Secondly:

> I have another form with the id of
>   ofform-reset and if i use:

You need to change this. It's invalid markup to have multiple ID's. If I understood you wrong here, the first solution might also help you here, invoking the `.find()` method aswell:

```
var serializedReturn = $('#ofform').find('input[name!=security]').serialize();
```

Comment: As to your second point, I'm not sure that's what he meant. I'm assuming he meant to use a subjunctive clause: "...I have another form with the `id` of 'form-reset,' and if I use..." But I could be wrong.

Comment: @David: yes I had the same idea, added a few lines. And.. "he" is probably a "she" :)

Comment: and my previous comment could've totally used another comma after the word 'form,' in order to make actual sense... =) As for my gender confusion, wow. Umm...sorry 'bout that, @Helga (I didn't actually look at your name before posting... @_@ )

Comment: no worries!  but the .find() method you indicate is still picking up the inputs on my 2nd form.  first form (#ofform) has all the inputs and second form (#ofform-reset) has the reset button- so i don't have 2 elements with the same ID.

Comment: i think it will ignore select element

Answer (score 13):

I am not happy with `'input[name!=security]'` because it exclude all other input type like `select`,.. You can add them manually but this list just keep increasing with new HTML tags. So with every new tag coming, your code is broken again.

Here is my solution:

```
$form.find(':not(input[name=draft])').serialize()
```

or

```
$('form[name=expenses] :not(input[name=draft])').serialize()
```

Space is very important in second example.

Answer (score 9):

In my situation, this worked fine:

```
$("fieldset").not(".tasks-container").serialize()
```

Comment: does not work for me, jAndy's solution above works for me

Answer (score 4):

***Solved!*** You should use the given solution to exclude input field to be serialized.
It's tested and solved my problem.

```
var formdata = $($("#myform")[0].elements).not("#field_id").serialize();
```

for multiple fields, you can use the class name to exclude them.

```
var formdata = $($("#myform")[0].elements).not(".class_name").serialize();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter result array

```
var ignoreFields = ["_csrf"];

$('form')
 .serializeArray()
 .filter(function(val){
    return ignoreFields.indexOf(val.name) === -1;
 });
```

Or shorter variant

```
$('form').serializeArray().filter(val => ignoreFields.indexOf(val.name) === -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = $.param($.map($("#form_name").serializeArray(), function(v,i) {
   return (v.name.includes("substring")) ? null : v;
}));
```