# JQuery: how to exclude an option from .serialize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of form elements in my form like this:

```
<select id="sectionNumber" name="sectionNumber">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

I send this form as an AJAX request.

```
$.getJSON("myAction.action", $('#myForm').serialize(), processData);
```

If **All** is selected, is there an easy way to exclude the `sectionNumber=All` string from the `.serialize()` return value? I have a bunch of these, and not all of them have an `All` option.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556172/excluding-certain-inputs-on-serialize

Comment: Can't you just make the value the empty string?  That's the canonical way of representing that the user didn't make a specific choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the value empty, like @tvanfosson suggest. But if you really need the `"All"` value you can filter the fields then you serialize it again.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ATXbt/

Comment: I like this approach the best. @theCodeParadox's approach is good as well, but more suited to a small number of replacements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myForm').serialize().replace('sectionNumber=All&','');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never use the "All" value for anyhting, don't set it in your markup and leave it as

```
<option value="">All</option>
```

By doing this you won't have to write a bunch of extra script

Comment: I tried this, and `.serialize()` still adds `sectionNumber=` to the string.

Comment: there's likely a simple solution such as a disable rule... disabled fields don't get serialized

Comment: can you give more info on the disable rule, like point to some documentation?

Comment: a disabled field won't submit or be serialized. See link regarding "successful controls"  http://api.jquery.com/serialize/  so somewhere in your logic you could use prop() method to disable fields

Answer (score 0):

It's old thread but I hope someone will find it usefull.
To exclude empty values you can use this:

```
':not(:empty)'
```