# Form Get Method: prevent empty fields from submittion in query string

Tags: jquery, forms, get

I am developing a search form.

Search Form has 2 parts, 
First simple search with some select, input, and submit button.
Second contains many select, check box, radio, input and submit button.

I am using GET method as i want all fields in query string like. 
example.com/cars-parts/cars-for-sale/?country=205&city=19&cars_category=462

But the issue is if user don't select some fields(because he donot want to apply this criteria) a lot of empty fields and make query string too long.

Problem:

I want to remove (disable or whatever needed) all empty fields before form submission, so that query string includes only fields having value.

NOTE: Only suggest using Form Get Method. In Past i was using POST method and no values were passed in query string, but now i want values in query string.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Hiya Asad - this is actually a duplicate of an existing question, but in case it's still of any use to you, I've just posted a different option on the original [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926673/how-can-i-remove-empty-fields-from-my-form-in-the-querystring/30009333#30009333).

The short version is that (on Apache) using a mod-rewrite rule might be a better solution if you want to be sure that the fields are correctly removed when a user isn't using Javascript.

Comment: Yes it helps, appreciate your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a function on the form submit event and remove/disable all input with an empty value. Like this :

```
your_form.submit(function() {
    your_form.find('input').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (!input.val()) {
            input.remove(); // or input.prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes you are right, but it will only remove input, as i stated in question there can be select, checkbox, radio etc.

Comment: Currently write one, $('#frm_search').submit(function(){
$(this).find(':input[value=""]').prop('disabled', true);
$(this).find('select').not(":selected").prop('disabled', true);
  
  return true;
  });

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following in your `$(function(){ ... })` section:

```
$('form').submit(function(){$('input[value=]',this).remove();return true;})
```

this will remove any empty `input` elements from your form before submitting it. You can of course modify it to include also non-selected selector boxes etc.

Comment: This will not remove _empty_ `input` elements, but it will remove input elements which _do not have a `value="…"` set_.

Comment: Quinn is absolutely right - haven't been here for a while ... 
However, this *will*  work: 
`$('form').submit(function(){
  $('input').each(function(){with($(this)) if (val()=='') remove();})
})`

Comment: Oooops, the above comment, of course, is essentially Magus's answer - sorry for repeating it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to validate all those fields before including into the `.get()` method and do  not include to the `.get()` method those inputs that has no values.