# Hide the text input field portion in a form's GET query url when the value is an empty string

Tags: html, django, forms, get

e.g.: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/database/?reference_doi=&submit=Submit`

I know It appears to be an html standard, but is there a tag to switch it, so that the empty text input string does not appear in the query url?

Or alternatively, since I'm using Django, I tried doing the following in my view.

```
request_get_copy = request.GET.copy()
for key, value in request_get_copy.items():
    if not value or key == 'submit':
        request_get_copy.pop(key)

request.GET = request_get_copy
request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = request_get_copy.urlencode()
```

I displayed request.GET and request.META['QUERY_STRING'] in the actual page through my template, and several methods that request object has, and they all gave successfully "corrected" values, like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/database/` But since the GET request first goes through the browser, the displayed url still contains empty string value portions. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, are you trying to remove a key from the querystring if it has no value?

Comment: Yes, but not only when I start to process it in the backend, also the `corrected` querystring should appear on the user's browser when s/he clicks `Submit`.

Comment: Hi terencezl - no, there is not a tag to accomplish what you're asking (maybe one day, but not yet).  There are other options, though.

This is a very similar question to what's been asked before - but [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926673/how-can-i-remove-empty-fields-from-my-form-in-the-querystring/30009333#30009333) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829379/form-get-method-prevent-empty-fields-from-submittion-in-query-string) for further suggestions.

I've left a response on using mod_rewrite on the first page, which may be more robust than Javascript options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing you could do is to issue a redirect to your fixed URL:

```
fixed_url = request_get_copy.urlencode()
return redirect(fixed_url)
```

Even better if you do that only if it actually changed, and before any DB access or heavy work.

This means an additional GET, but gives you the result you want, and I guess that's more valuable to you :)

If Javascript is an option, you could also do this changes *before* the submit actually happens, it's a tad more convoluted but will avoid the extra request.

**Edit:** Just to be clear, there's no way to "turn it off", you could say this is how HTTP and browsers work :)

Comment: I think you meant `reverse('some_namespace:database') + '?' + request_get_copy.urlencode()`. Yes, it worked very nicely.

Comment: How do I check if the querying fields actually are changed? After hitting "Submit" of the query form and obtain `request.GET`, how do I know the url that form previously resided in, so that I can compare their query string (or parsed object)?

Comment: And it seems a very routine problem when one uses a form to do the querying. I'm sure someone would have been tired seeing all the empty values... and do something rather than a redirection.

Comment: By changed I just meant that you don't redirect if there wasn't any empty field, but I guess that was obvious :) I wouldn't consider it to be a problem at all, users don't even look at the URL (that's how some scams work lol), and me personally, I care about the URL structure a lot, but also think explicit is better than implicit :D. Anyway, like I said, this is how HTTP works, and for all that "makeup" you use Javascript :) you can even control how the URL *looks*!