# Can I exclude a input field from form.reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a form.reload piece of JS that adds the chosen form dropdown to a variable, and to the head of the document so I can pass variables to the next page.

Sadly, my form reload is removing input fields that have been inputted.

Here's my simple JS reloading the form:

```
    function reload(form) {
    var val=form.cat.value;
    var val2=form.cat2.value;
    var val3=form.val3.value;
    var val4=form.val4.value;
    var val5=form.val5.value;
    self.location='mypage.php?val=' + val + '&val1=' + val2 + '&val2=' + val3 + '&val4=' + val4 + '&val5=' + val5;
    }
```

My call:

```
<select name='val' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\">
```

It's removing (reloading) my inputs. Is there a way around this? 
I want to keep the form input when reloading the form.

Comment: Why are you reloading the form instead of just changing the values of the inputs?

Comment: in mypage.php assign the values to the input fields, take them from $_GET array e.g. echo '<input type="text" name="'.$fieldName.'" value="'.$_GET[$fieldName].'" />';

Comment: It's just adding the variable into the URL so I can base output on selected items. Only way I could see of doing it. i.e Client has Projects, only out Projects of the Client selected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use jQuery's form.serialize but exclude empty fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this in your php file

```
<input type='text' name='cat' value='<?php print $_REQUEST[val]; ?>'>
```

an alternate suggestion to add all the values to the header is this

```
function reload(form) {
    self.location='mypage.php?' + $(form).serialize();
}
```

Comment: What if the val isn't in my header, it's just a <input> value?

Comment: then the value will be blank. do you have default values you want to load? i can show u how i would do that. your 'self.location' line of code will put the values in your header

Comment: No default values, it's user inputted. I can place the input values in the header I suppose, but having such a long set of input fields may look awful? I do think I need to reload the form though, once a option is chosen.

Comment: you should take a look at ajax. it sounds as if it may be the best option. you can retrieve new data from your server based on the input values, then change your form based on the results from the server http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yeah, sounds like I'll have to. Thanks buddy!

Comment: my pleasure, i edited my answer to add a suggestion on a clean way to add the values to the header.  good luck