# Remove empty fields/inputs from Serialize string

Tags: jquery, serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use jQuery's form.serialize but exclude empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields)

I need to remove the unused input names from a Serialize string if they're not filled in on a form. See the attached JSFIddle. Currently if someone only fills in Q1 & Q3 the names the string appears as follows `/static/url/to/file.php?Q1=Bob&Q2=&Q3=Dan&Q4=`. I'd therefore like to get rid of the `Q2=` and `Q4=` names from the string before submission. Thanks

[JSFiddle - Serialize](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmcx/125/)

Comment: [How do I use jQuery's form.serialize but exclude empty fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields)

Comment: Thanks Des, I can't quite get it to work in my code for some reason? I must be doing something wrong the bloody string keeps disappearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#form1').find('input[type="text"]').not('#url').change(function(){
    var val = "";
    var url = '/static/url/to/file.php?';
    $('form input[type="text"]').not('#url').each(function(){
        if ($.trim(this.value).length > 0 ) { 
          val += ($(this).attr('name') + "=" + this.value + "&");
        }  
    })
    $('#url').val(url+val);
});

$('#button').click(function(){
    window.location = $('#url').val();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmcx/133/)

Comment: Thanks...I just need the input answers to attach themselves to the URL in the visible result box? The results box is hidden behind a submit button. Sorry I'm a bit of a jquery novice.

Comment: Great stuff..many thanks. One problem, the Demo seems to be including the url twice in the results box?

Comment: @SamuelTattersfield you are welcome. not for me on firefox.

Comment: Strange...I'm on Firefox also, I also tried it in chrome and the string looked like so /static/url/to/file.php?Q1=bob&Q3=dan&Q4=rob&url=/static/url/to/file.php?Q1=bob&Q3=dan&url=/static/url/to/file.php?Q1=bob&&&

Comment: Still giving the same results?

Comment: @SamuelTattersfield chnage the each loop with `$('form input[type="text"]:not("input#url")').each(function(){`

Comment: I just tried it on an iPad to see if it was the browser...it gave the same results? very strange.....I'll try that loop code.

Comment: @SamuelTattersfield Fine, you are welcome, good luck :)

Comment: Thanks...sorry to be a pain but if I wanted to include a 'select' option to the form what would I need to add to the Jquery code?

Comment: @SamuelTattersfield don't mention it, this should do the trick, `$('form input[type="text"]:not("input#url, select")')`

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle with the above code and a select option however the select option is not pulling through? http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmcx/151/