# send all data from form without one

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use jQuery’s form.serialize but exclude empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields)

I would like to send all values from fields in a form using ajax without value from field "lastname" - how can I do that? My code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#other').click(function () {
            $.post("/Home/About", $("#target").serialize());
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="target" action="/Home/About" method="post">
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
    .....other fields.....
    Last name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><br>
</form>
<div id="other">Submit</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:not` selector:

```
$.post("/Home/About", $("#target :not(#lastname)").serialize());
```