# How to remove empty input field from a form using jquery for using serialize?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, input

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
var values = form.serialize();

//do some ajax calls
})
```

Now I want to do something like this

```
$("#myForm :input[value]").serialize() on the parent form
```

but I cant find a way to do this.I am guessing I have to use .find()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use jQuery's form.serialize but exclude empty fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see or understand the question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields I am trying to achieve what is asked here except that I am not using an id selector

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I get this, but the context selector is a shortcut for `find()`, and `this.form` should be the parent form ?

```
$(":input[value!='']", this.form).serialize()
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do

```
var values = $(this).parents('form:first').find(":input[value][value!='']").serialize();
```

or in your second case,

```
var values = $("#myForm :input[value][value!='']").serialize();
```

See related question for more details.

Comment: I am trying to do the first one but my values string contains only a radio button value

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the problem is but

```
$(":input[value!='']", this.form).serialize()
```

is not working for me and I am not sure what it does as it seems to filter only default values
 I spent too much time to get that to work and ended up manually filtering the inputs

```
var data={};
var formData = form.serializeArray();
$.each(formData, function (index, value) {
    var data_name = formData[index].name;
    var data_value = formData[index].value;
    if (data_value !== "") {
        data[data_name] = data_value;
    }
});
```