# Cant use use jQuery's form.serialize excluding empty fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, input

[How do I use jQuery's form.serialize but exclude empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields) I have the same problem as mentioned here and i am trying to use the answer

```
var form = $(this).parents('form:first');//this is inside the button.clicks callback 
var values = form.find(':input').not('[value=""]').serialize();
```

but this doesn't seem to work

```
values = form.find(":input[value][value!='']").serialize();
```

this  also is  not working what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the empty elements serialize then enable them back

```
form.find(":input").each(function(){
    if (this.value == '') this.disabled = true;
})
values = form.serialize();
form.find(":input:disabled").prop('disabled',false);
```

Comment: $("#vmuform").find(":input[value!='']") is selecting empty fields

Comment: @Nithin it doesn't matter how you select the empty fields, just disable them then serialize the form.

Comment: sorry about that i meant $("#vmuform").find(":input[value!='']") is not selecting those fields ,I figured out what was wrong ,I did not specify an initial value for the input field and the value was undefined so myy selectors were not working.