# "How do I use jQuery's form.serialize but exclude empty fields" does not work (with php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'd like to use [How do I use jQuery's form.serialize but exclude empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields) but it does not work. I used a minimal example that redirects to a php script:

```
<html><head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(){
        $("#myForm :input[value!='']").serialize();
        alert('JavaScript done');
    });
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="php.php" method="get">
       <input id=id1 name=name1 type="text" /><br>
       <input id=id2 name=name2 type="text" /><br>
       <input id=id3 name=name3 type="text" /><br>
       <input id=id4 name=name4 type="text" />
       <input type="submit" value="submit form"/>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

An here is the php script

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

If I write "111" only into the first textbox, I get from php:

```
Array ( [name1] => 111 [name2] => [name3] => [name4] => )
```

Thus, all fields made it into the get parameters.

Can you please help me?

TIA

Comment: You need to AJAX the form - just calling serialize does not remove the fields from the request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use attribute selector for `value` as it is a changing property.

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        $(this).find(":input").filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.value).length > 0
        }).serialize();
        alert('JavaScript done');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e37XZ/)

*Note: just serializing the input fields does not change in form submission, it can be used only if the form is submitted via ajax.*

If you want to do a normal form submission but want to remove the empty fields then use [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        $(this).find(":input").filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.value).length == 0
        }).remove();
        alert('JavaScript done');
    });
});
```

Comment: This do not seem to change the output, all the empty fields made it into get parameters...

Comment: It work if I change the froth line to "return $.trim(this.value).length <= 0".

Answer (score 1):

You need to AJAX the form - just calling serialize does not remove the fields from the request

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fw9pe/)

```
$('#myForm').on("submit",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the form itself
    var opts = $(this).find(":input").filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
    }).serialize();
    $.get($('#myForm').attr("action"),opts,function(data) {
       alert(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with ajax, and get the array data in php file, see below code.

```
<html><head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_form').click(function(e){
    $("#myForm :input[value!='']").serialize();
    var form_data= $("#myForm :input[value!='']").serializeArray();
    $.post("php.php",form_data,function(data){
         alert('JavaScript done');
    },"json");      
   e.preventDefault();

   });


});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<form id="myForm">
   <input id=id1 name=name1 type="text" /><br>
   <input id=id2 name=name2 type="text" /><br>
   <input id=id3 name=name3 type="text" /><br>
   <input id=id4 name=name4 type="text" />
   <input type="submit" id="submit_form" value="submit form"/>
</form>
```