# jQuery :not() Selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to exclude selects with empty values from serialization.

I'm trying to achieve this like so:

```
    var form = $('#myForm');
    var str = $(':not(select[value=""])', form).serialize();
```

No erros, and the result is the entire form. The not() method gives the same.

What is possibly wrong?

**EDIT:** The question which was listed as possible duplicate to mine asks about possible implemntations for exlcuding empty fields frm serialization, while mine states that `not() Selector` doesn't work, asks why and for different to above mentioned solution.

Comment: What is in your form? If there's anything other than a `<select>` element whose current value is `""`, they'll be included.

Comment: Why not just disable those elements? Disabled elements aren't serialized, IIRC.

Comment: @Pointy It contains a lot of elemetns such as numerous selects and text inputs, all of which I want to serialize but selects with empty values.

Comment: @Mike I was thinking about that, but I believe It wouldn't be as elegant and reliable as filtering unnecessary element on the serialization stage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use jQuery's form.serialize but exclude empty fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields)

Comment: Note that the select must have an attribute that matches, or in other word *it must look like* `<select value="">` where it actually has the attribute, and the attributes value matches the selector. You probably want to filter on the property instead.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which filters element with element attribute `value` which equals to an empty string and not the element with current value as an empty string.

---

For filtering element with current value as empty string use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method.

```
var str = $(':input', form).filter(function(){
   return this.value.trim() != '';
}).serialize();
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you just want to avoid empty `select` tags then do it like.

```
var str = $(':input', form).filter(function(){
   return !($(this).is('select') && this.value.trim() == '');
}).serialize();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with this implementation I have exactly the same results.

Comment: Thank you. It does seem to do the job, however for some reason not empty input text is not serialized anymore.